# How to get a label's ID when clicked?

Tags: vb.net, label, addhandler

I'm having problems with getting the ID from a label when using a AddHandler, this is an example but i am also using this for control arrays which labels.

```
AddHandler CmdUpdate.Click, AddressOf CmdUpdate_click

Protected Sub CmdUpdate_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
 '?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sender.Name` property.

You should cast `sender` to a `Control`:

```
DirectCast(sender, Control).Name
```